# How do I edit my segue target data through prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, segue

I am trying to edit the segue's target's data through `prepareForSegue`, but everything I try keeps returning the "unrecognized selector sent to instance ..." error. Is there a special way to edit my target's data, is it being deleted before I edit it or something like that? I just started picking this stuff up so I still don't have my head all the way around it. Here is a sample of some of my code

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"managerSegue"]){
    ASExpenseList *target = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *row = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    self.cellPressed = row.row;

    switch(self.cellPressed){
        case 0:
            [target initWithData:self.oneTimeExpenses]; //PROBLEM LINE
           // target.expenses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.oneTimeExpenses]; ALSO PROBLEM
            target.title = @"One-Time"; //not breaking the program but not working
```

The `ASExpenseList` function I'm calling is really simple:

```
-(void) initWithData:(NSMutableArray *)newExpenses {
self.expenses = newExpenses;
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

So I am trying to set the target's data to some data I already have, and I am trying to dynamically change the title. The title change isn't working and the data lines are throwing errors. I'm guessing that I just misunderstand how it works, so any help or clarification would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Only set target properties in `prepareForSegue` and initialize or set it up in the `viewDidLoad` ...

Comment: It's not a good practice to start a method name with init, if it's not actually an init method (i.e. one that has id as the return type and returns self).

Comment: @dasdom That doesn't make any sense. `title` is a property of the target view controller, not one of its views. Storyboards work perfectly well, though understanding how to use them correctly can take some time, especially for developers who are relatively inexperienced with Interface Builder.

Comment: Oh, right. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: So should the line 'target.expenses = self.oneTimeExpenses;' work? Because it doesn't, it throws the same exception (Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController initWithData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8aa0140')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the actual "unrecognized selector sent to instance ..." error you're getting? Different things can be going wrong here depending on what selector is being sent to what object.

But generally, when you're dealing with "unrecognized selector", step 0 is to determine if the object is really what you think it is. In this case, make sure `[segue destinationViewController]` really is an `ASExpenseList`. I have my doubts, as `ASExpenseList` sounds like a model or a view, and `[segue destinationViewController]` as the name implies, returns a view controller.

Some strategies for verifying the identity of the `destinationViewController` include:

- `NSLog("dest: %@", [segue destinationViewController]);`
- `NSLog("dest class: %@", [segue destinationViewController]);`
- Placing a breakpoint and examining `target` in Variables View.
- Placing a breakpoint and interrogating `target` with `po` in LLDB.

Comment: Here is the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController initWithData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8aa0140'

And as for the ASExpenseList being referenced I have placed a breakpoint and "target" has the array "expenses" but you're right, it is a "UINavigationController".

Comment: Right. In a segue you get passed a view *controller* that manages the view you're segueing too. In the simplest case, your custom view (`ASExpenseList`?) is the view of the controller. So you could write: `[[target view] setExpenses:…]`. If `ASExpenseList` is a subview of the controller's view, you'll have to navigate to it some other way, most likely by adding it as an outlet to the view controller: `[[target myOutlet] setExpenses:…]`

Comment: 'ASExpenseList' is a view controller (subclass of UITableViewController or something similar). [[target view] initWithData:...] is giving me a red error of "No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'initWithData:'" (sorry if I'm missing the obvious)

Comment: I'm sorry. I can tell you what's wrong (you're trying to treat the `destinationViewController` of the segue as if it's an `ASExpenseList`, but it's *not*. It's a `UINavigationController`) but you don't give me enough information to tell you how to fix it. I suggest you go back to the WWDC videos/sample code/etc. on segues and review the basics.

Comment: See the video titled [Adopting Storyboards in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/).

Comment: You were right, I was just misunderstanding how it worked. Rewrote the whole app to get a better understanding and now I'm dodging that error. Thank you so much for pointing me to those resources and getting me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a segue, the storyboard handles the alloc + init of a UIViewController, so you don't need to do the initialization. You can set data by using the properties.

Comment: He is not initializing it, its just that the function name is called `initWithData'

Comment: Correct, I am trying to set the array that is already there to an existing array that I have. And also change the title and maybe disable a navigation button. -- The problem is that trying to set data is throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `newExpenses` as a property in your `ASExpenseList` class. Set it in your `prepareForSegue` and populate the tableView in your `viewDidLoad` in `ASExpenseList` using the NSArray you passed.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit further? I have a property called "expenses", which I am already setting. But any attempt to set it through 'prepareForSegue' is throwing errors at me.

Comment: It should be as simple as target.expenses = self.oneTimeExpenses; Could you post the whole content of those classes? Maybe something else is missing.